# write() in netty not working. Huge delay before making it to handlers

Tags: netty

Our pipeline uses an NIO worker group with 10 threads.

Our pipeline is setup as follows:

```
ch.pipeline().addLast(new IdleStateHandler(0, 0, 10, TimeUnit.Seconds))
             .addLast(sslHandler)
             .addLast(businessLogicHandler)
             .addLast(defaultEventExecutorWith5Threads, exceptionHandler)
```

ExceptionHandler does nothing on write() except call write again and wait on the promise so it can detect any failures.  It looks something like this:

```
    ctx.write(msg, promise.addListener(new ChannelFutureListener() {
        @Override
        public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture future) {
            if (!future.isSuccess()) {
                // Handle write exception here...
            }
        }
    }))
```

we are seeing roughly 10 seconds of sporadic delay between exceptionHandler and businessLogicHandler. In other words, we call:

```
channel.write(message);
```

It shows up instantly in exceptionHandler, and then takes 10 seconds to make it to businessLogicHandler.  However the delay is not 100% consistent.  Just very frequent.

We have noticed that if we call channel.writeAndFlush(message), that seems to mitigate the issue, however I can't understand why that would be.  My understanding was that:

write() will send a message down the pipeline at the end of which it is buffered in front of the socket.  If the buffer fills up, netty automatically pushes it over the wire.

flush() will force the buffer before the socket to flush().

That being that case, I can't see why flush would make any difference in the propagation of a message down the pipeline. I could understand if we weren't seeing the message pass over the wire though.

UPDATE:
The delay corresponds exactly to the timeout specified in the IdleStateHandler.  Propagation down the pipeline blocks at random handlers for exactly 10 seconds in the current example.  If you set the timeout to 30 seconds, the random blocking happens for 30 seconds at random.

UPDATE:
I'm starting to think this might have something to do with this:
https://github.com/netty/netty/commit/f44f3e7926f1676315ae86d0f18bdd9b95681d9f

UPDATE:
I've opened an issue for Netty since I think the race condition described in the previous comment still exists.  https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/7719